# How come my carousel is much wider than the rest of my page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I want to make it so that the width of my carousel is the same as my header and navigation bar but instead it takes up the whole width of the page. How do I change this?

I am using this https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/ as a template but when I try to add the carousel snippet from here
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-bs-carousel-with-hero-headers
its width is 100%.

How do I go about changing it so that it is the same width as the rest of the page and does not take up 100% of it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using container class for your `carousel` `<div class="carousel fade-carousel slide container" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000" id="bs-carousel">` like this

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

just place ur code inside `class="container"` like below and it should work see updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26753/)

```
<div class="container">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="./">Default <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
              <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>





<div class="carousel fade-carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000" id="bs-carousel">
  <!-- Overlay -->
  <div class="overlay"></div>

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item slides active">
      <div class="slide-1"></div>
      <div class="hero">
        <hgroup>
            <h1>We are creative</h1>        
            <h3>Get start your next awesome project</h3>
        </hgroup>
        <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">See all features</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item slides">
      <div class="slide-2"></div>
      <div class="hero">        
        <hgroup>
            <h1>We are smart</h1>        
            <h3>Get start your next awesome project</h3>
        </hgroup>       
        <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">See all features</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item slides">
      <div class="slide-3"></div>
      <div class="hero">        
        <hgroup>
            <h1>We are amazing</h1>        
            <h3>Get start your next awesome project</h3>
        </hgroup>
        <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">See all features</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is seeming like the rest of your contents are inside **row** or **container** and what I can see from the carousel snippet is that it is not inside any **row** or **container** which is making it to take the full width by 100% width.

Try inserting the carousel inside a container or row which is most relevant to other portions of your page. That should solve your problem.

If you post your codes then the problem could be gone through more well.